# Xamarin.Forms Android Local Notification Not Sending

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have followed the Xamarin walkthrough, and it's not working for me.
The code falls through this cleanly, but it never sends the notification.
It never shows up on my emulator or device.

I have no idea what is going on.

```
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        string message = intent.GetStringExtra("message");
        string title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");
        int id = int.Parse(intent.GetStringExtra("id"));

        //Generate a notification with just short text and small icon
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)                    // Dismiss from the notif. area when clicked
                        .SetContentTitle(title)      // Set its title
                        .SetContentText(message); // The message to display.


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
        notificationManager.Notify(id, builder.Build());
```

Any help or links would be very helpful. I'm just completely lost; been working on this for about 14 hours now, and cannot find any help on the Google.

Answer to my inquiry: You must have an Icon set for notifications to be properly build and sent. Though, it won't send an error for not having one.

Short version: Needed to add

```
 .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an icon to notification.

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder (this)
.SetContentTitle ("Title")
.SetContentText ("Message")
.SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.ic_notification);

Notification notification = builder.Build();

NotificationManager notificationManager = 
       GetSystemService (Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

const int notificationId = 0;
notificationManager.Notify (notificationId, notification);
```

Comment: Ah! I see, you are required to have an Icon. I hadn't thought about that. It was just a functional test.